# jqtransform don't transform the values received from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have this java script:

```
    $("#judet div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").click(function(){     
var jud= $("#judetul1").val(); 
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rental/cms/inc/ajax/cities.php",
        data: { 'jud': jud },
        success: function (msg) {

            $("#oras1").html(msg);

        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });     
    });
```

and this html:

```
<div class=" h">
   <span class="block">Orasul</span>
   <div class="select6" id="oras">

   <select name="oras1" id="oras1"   onchange="zone1();sectorul();">

   </select>
  </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
```

and this php:

```
public function get_oras($code3) { 
echo "<option selected='selected' value='0'>Alege oras</option>";
        $code='PPLA';
        $code2='PPLA2';
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `locatii` WHERE (`feature_code`=:code OR `feature_code`=:code2) AND `admin1_code`=:code3 ORDER BY `asciiname` ASC";
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
        $stmt->bindParam(':code2', $code2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
        $stmt->bindParam(':code3', $code3, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result) 
        {
             $oras[]="<option value='".$result['geonameid']."'>".$result['asciiname']."</option>";

        }
    return $oras;

}
```

html for judetul:

```
<div class=" h">
 <span class="block">Judetul</span>
  <div class="select6" id="judet">
  <?php $judetul=$db->get_judet(); ?>
  <select name="judetul1" id="judetul1"  >
  <option selected="selected">---</option>
  <?php foreach ($judetul as $val=>$k) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $val; ?>"><?php echo $k; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

The problem is:

without the jqtransform the scripts work very fine, but if I include jqtransform the select oras1 is not populated.
I think it's a problem because I transform a form first and then I populate with values...so that values will not be transformed into my oras1 select.

How can I fix it?
Can I transform the select after I populate it with values?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct, the jqTransform transform your select box at document-ready.
The appearance you see on select box after jqTransform is a wrapper.
Therefore, the update in the select's  after your ajax request is only affecting the hidden select element but not the wrapper.

You can try re-jqTransfrom the select box to get it right.

Or, visit my blog
http://infrahtml.blogspot.hk/2013/12/jstransform-select-box-repopulation.html
to make changes to the plugins